# get common data by combining data of three differrent sql query

Tags: mysql, subquery

```
SELECT STATNO FROM ENQUIRY  WHERE ID=12;
```

Returns: 100,102,110

```
SELECT STATNO FROM ENQUIRY  WHERE ID=16;
```

Returns: 102,112,118

```
 SELECT STATNO FROM ENQUIRY  WHERE ID=21;
```

Returns: 101,102,120

I need a query that combines the above and returns the common data: 102.

Comment: no wonder, he has never got an answer here at SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drop table if exists enquiry;
create table enquiry (id integer, statno integer);
insert into enquiry values 
(12,100),(12,102),(12,110),
(18,102),(18,112),(18,118),
(21,101),(21,102),(21,120);

select distinct statno from enquiry where 
statno in (select statno from enquiry where id=12)
and statno in (select statno from enquiry where id=18)
and statno in (select statno from enquiry where id=21)
;
```

Comment: Thank u Alex Monthy...U solved my problem...it works fine...Thank u once again

Comment: @Brittas you should choose it as an answer by clicking the tick symbol near the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use JOIN in your query:

```
SELECT a.STATNO FROM ENQUIRY a
JOIN (
   SELECT x.STATNO FROM ENQUIRY x WHERE ID=16
) b ON a.STATNO = b.STATNO
JOIN (
   SELECT y.STATNO FROM ENQUIRY y WHERE ID=21
) c ON b.STATNO = c.STATNO
 WHERE a.ID=12
```

Comment: `EXISTS` doesnt work here, the first one is the answer in fact

Comment: @nawfal yeah, you're right...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `INTERSECT` doesnt work with MySQL. You could do this instead..

```
SELECT     a.STATNO
FROM       ENQUIRY AS a 
INNER JOIN ENQUIRY AS b ON b.STATNO = a.STATNO 
INNER JOIN ENQUIRY AS c on c.STATNO = a.STATNO 
WHERE a.id = 12 and b.id = 16 and c.id =21
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use group by with having statement

```
SELECT STATNO FROM ENQUIRY  WHERE ID IN (12 ,16 , 21) group by STATNO having count(*)  = 3;
```

This approach will only work if the `combination of (ID, STATNO) is unique`. Here `count(*) would be equal to total number of values in IN statement in query like here is 3`.

thanks